# How to update variable in d3 chart using ajax in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, d3.js

I will update data variable in d3 chart scripts without refreshing the screen using ajax which the variable sent from view.py. How to update it, the variable in d3 chart is `{{totalSalesGraph|safe}}`

**htmlFile.html**

```
<html>
    <div class="graphTotalSale">
        <div id="graphSale"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{% url 'updateData' %}"
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                  // how to update {{totalSalesGraph}} variable in d3 chart. (new value is response.totalSalesGraph)
            });
        }, 5000)
    </script>
    <script>
        var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
            width = 550
            height = 120

        var svg = d3.select("#graphSale")
        ...

        //Read the data
        var data = {{totalSalesGraph|safe}}
        ...
    </script>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at javascript [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). You can use them to overload the update of totalSalesGraph to actually rerender the d3 svg. Here is a more [in-depth explanation of proxies.](https://codeburst.io/understanding-javascript-proxies-by-examining-on-change-library-f252eddf76c2)